# Drush Enable a module and all its submodules

Tags: drush

For example when I enable `coder`  module, I also want to enable `coder_review`, `coder_sniffer` and `coder_upgrade` modules.

Comment: That's an extremely niche bit of functionality to need...surely this would only be useful on a tiny handful of modules? Plus you'd need to check what modules _could_ be installed each time you do it, to make sure you don't accidentally enable a sub-module that you don't want. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box, however you can just list the three modules and then coder will also be enabled as it's a dependency.

E.g. `drush en coder_review coder_sniffer coder_upgrade -y`

If there are more modules than this that you might want, then seriously try taking a look at the [Master](https://drupal.org/project/master) module.

> The module provides utilities for controlling the module status of all modules in > the whole installation by a single drush command.

I've got various scopes set up on all of my sites, (including local scopes for my machine) so that when I run `drush master-exec --scope=mattlocal`, I get modules enabled that no other environment should have (e.g. DummyImages, Devel, Coder)

Lastly, a cheap workaround would be to have a custom module (maybe a controller module if you have one), and just make Coder and all of it's submodules dependencies and enable that.

E.g.

```
name = MyModule
description = This module does nothing except for handle dependencies.
package = Custom
core = 7.x
version = 7.x-1.x

dependencies[] = coder
dependencies[] = coder_sniffer
dependencies[] = coder_upgrade
dependencies[] = coder_review
```

and then

`drush en mymodule`

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing out of the box to automatically enable *submodules*, but it is, in fact, possible to specify similarly-named modules via a wildcard:

```
drush en 'coder*'
```

As previously mentioned, this is only useful in certain niche situations.  I have never used it in any practical situation.  If you happened to need it, it would be just the thing, though.